# 'invalid file specification' when running Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: stata

I programmed the Monte Carlo simulation down below. The simulation itself works, but I do not seem able to `summarize` it. When I run my full program, the do file automatically ends after the Monte Carlo simulation and does not run the last three lines of my code. When I run it manually after the do file has stopped I get the error: 'invalid file specification'. Does anyone has experience with this?

```
foreach n in 30 1600 {
local j = 1
while `j' <= 1000 {
quietly {
preserve
sample `n', count
noisily  di in yellow  "." _continue

gen y3_m = 1 + 1*w + v3
replace y3_m = y3_m > 0

gen y2_m = 1 + 1*x + 1*z1 +1*z2 + 1*v1 + 1*v2
replace y2_m =. if y3_m <= 0

gen y1_m = 1 + 1*y2_m + 1*x + v1
replace y1_m =. if y3_m <= 0
    probit y3_m w

*step 2

predict eventpr_m, xb
gen PDFprobit_m = normalden(eventpr)
gen CDFprobit_m = normprob(eventpr)
gen IMR_m = PDFprobit/CDFprobit

ivregress 2sls y1_m x IMR_m (y2 = z1 z2)
matrix b1=e(b) 
svmat b1, name(Ivreg) // save the regression coefficients and collapse in
// order to only have one observation per coefficient

collapse (mean) Ivreg* 

gen N = `n'

if `j' > 1 {
append using `mc`n'' 
}

save `mc`n'', replace
restore
local j = `j' + 1
}
}
di "`n'"
}

use `mc30', clear
append using `mc1600'
summarize
```

Comment: This seems more a programming problem than a statistical problem. This is why I voted to move this to stackoverflow.

Comment: Please see also my request of Feb 23 within http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680167/errorno-variables-defined-in-stata-when-using-monte-carlo-simulation that you clean up after yourself by deleting threads that went nowhere.

Comment: I believe the `clear' after the use removes the local macro `mc1600', so Stata does not recognize `mc1600' (as its a non-existing local, thus blank). a possible solution would be to write append using mc1600 without the quotes. However, the same problem seems to appear where you save ``mc`n''`, I think it should be save mc`n' as I cant see `mc' defined anywhere.

Comment: @German Tapia. I guess your comment was made about the same time as my post. I agree that the use, or rather misunderstanding, of local macros is part of the problem here. But there is no sense in which  `use, clear` removes any local macro. Also, unless the local macro named `mc1600` contained the text `"mc1600"` then no such file exists so far as we know.

Comment: @GermanTapia You'll presumably see a problem with your comment as backticks for mark-up here conflict with any desire to use backticks as part of Stata syntax.

Comment: @Nick Cox: thanks for the clarification, I thought clear removed local macros. I saw and tried fixing the formatting in the comment above but did not manage...

Comment: Neither `use, clear` nor even `clear` removes local macros. That would make programming much more difficult.

Answer (score 4):

On any forum this has to be regarded as an awkward question: the dataset, or an equivalent, is nowhere explained or accessible and the code depends on local macro assignments made earlier; it appears that most of the code is tangential to the question. For future reference, please read [about minimal, complete, and verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I couldn't read the whole of the code easily without scrolling, so I copied it and trimmed it down to understand as much as possible. Here is an abbreviated version, making cosmetic changes, including but not only

1. Using `forval` rather than a `while` loop.
2. Removing variables inessential for the presented code (although naturally they may be needed for your later statistical purposes)
3. More use of indentation.
4. Removing multiplications by 1.

I have not tested this version for compatibility.

```
foreach n in 30 1600 {
    quietly forval j = 1/1000 { 
        preserve
        sample `n', count
        noisily  di in yellow  "." _continue

        gen y3_m = (1 + w + v3) > 0
        gen y2_m = 1 + x + z1 + z2 + v1 + v2
        replace y2_m =. if y3_m <= 0
        gen y1_m = 1 + y2_m + x + v1
        replace y1_m =. if y3_m <= 0

        probit y3_m w
        predict eventpr_m, xb
        gen IMR_m = normalden(eventpr)/normprob(eventpr)

        ivregress 2sls y1_m x IMR_m (y2 = z1 z2)
        matrix b1=e(b) 
        svmat b1, name(Ivreg)   
        collapse (mean) Ivreg* 

        gen N = `n'

        if `j' > 1 append using `mc`n'' 
        save `mc`n'', replace
        restore
    } // forval 
    di "`n'"
} // foreach 

use `mc30', clear
append using `mc1600'
summarize
```

The crunch appears to be that the code here was originally included in a do-file. The content implies that it was just the tail end of a do-file as otherwise the references within to local macros `mc30` and `mc1600` would seem invalid.

The problem with running the last three lines separately is immediate. Outside the context of the do-file, the local macro `mc30` is not defined; local macros are just as the term implies, local to the namespace of the program in which they are defined. So Stata sees just `use, clear`, which is illegal. A similar problem would bite with `mc1600`, but Stata doesn't get that far.

I can't say why the code as a self-contained do-file doesn't finish, but as said there is no reproducible example here to explore. You need to insert more checks and/or slim the code down to identify the problem.

Comment: Just to note that point 1, using `forvalues` rather than `while`, is not just cosmetic, but importantly, more efficient.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer I agree. My trying to improve (the readability of) the code was secondary to trying to understand it.

Comment: Should have added that my comment was primarily targeted at future readers initiating work with Stata. Nick, of course, knows what's going on.